# Using tikzset to set Arrow style and line width

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikzset

I'm using a tikzset command to set a global style

```
\tikzset{FARROW/.tip={Latex[angle=40:2.5mm]},
   FARROW/.style={line width=3mm}
}
```

When I use it for an arrow, the arrow head style conforms to the style, but the line width stays the same

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate (o) at (0,0);
        \coordinate (e) at (0,3);
        \coordinate (ball) at (0,3.05);
        \coordinate (i1) at (2,0.5);
        \coordinate (i2) at (2,2.5);
        \filldraw (ball) circle (0.05cm);
        \draw[-FARROW] (o)node[right]{O}--(e) node[right] {$x$};
        \draw[-FARROW] (i1)--(i2) node[right] {$\VEC{i}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Here's the output

[image: Output showing arrow head is set, but line width not]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It is better if you expand the code snippet sthat you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). It is much easier to help you if we can start with some compilable code that illustrates your problem. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, include any necessary packages and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. At the moment we have to guess what packages etc you are using before we can compile your code (and I have no idea what `\VEC` is:)

Comment: I'll remember that for future use, thanks. `\VEC` is a vector style `\newcommand{\VEC}[1]{\bm{\mathrm{#1}}}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
  FARROW/.style={line width=3mm, arrows={-Latex[angle=40:2.5mm]}}
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate (o) at (0,0);
        \coordinate (e) at (0,3);
        \coordinate (ball) at (0,3.05);
        \coordinate (i1) at (2,0.5);
        \coordinate (i2) at (2,2.5);
        \filldraw (ball) circle (0.05cm);
        \draw[FARROW] (o)node[right]{O}--(e) node[right] {$x$};
        \draw[FARROW] (i1)--(i2) node[right] {${i}$};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

to produce:

[image]

I hope that these line widths are just for demonstration purposes and you don't really want to use these:)

Comment: This is excellent, thank you. Yes, the line weights were there to give me a **big** indication it was working.